# Java Generics Type Casting

Tags: java, generics

Lets say...

```
<T, S extends T> void work(final Class<T> type, final S object) {}
```

or

```
<T> void work(final Class<T> type, final T object) {}
```

How can I pass following parameters to work()?

```
final Class<?> type = <not null> // This is actually an reflection output.
final Object object = <not null>

assert type.isInstance(object); // this is absolutely guaranteed

work(type, type.cast(object)); // compile error; how can I do this?
work(type, object); // compile error; how can I do this?
```

Comment: I changed the method like this. `void work(Class<?> type, Object object)` and I put a conditional check for `type.isInstance(object)`. Did I do right? Thank you.

Comment: Oh. I thank for all answers. But I can't choose all of them as the accepted answer. I'm sorry. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a `Class<T>` for this to work, but you can get that. Once you have that, you can simply do this:

```
work(type, type.cast(object));
```

Now, since you've got a `Class<?>` you can't simply assign it to a `Class<T>`, but you can work around this by providing an additional method:

```
<T> void checkedWork(final Class<T> type, final Object object) {
    work(type, type.cast(object));
}
```

Comment: I'd add the `isInstance` check to `checkedWork` since that'd have to be done anyway.

Comment: @Thomas: `Class.cast()` will throw a `ClassCastException` if the types don't match at runtime, so I'd say that's even more appropriate than using an `assert`.

Comment: If you want to deal with ClassCastExceptions at runtime, yes you can do that. I'd rather check first and try to avoid ClassCastExceptions at runtime.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I don't have to worry about the CCE because I located the type(Class<?>) with given object in reflection.

Comment: @Thomas: true, but for that you'd need correct and complete generics information so that the compiler can decide if it works (in which case you wouldn't need the `cast()` call. But the decision between `assert`/`cast()` is not relevant here, since both only happen at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you'd need complete generics information. That's why I talked about a rigid requirement (maybe the wording was inaccurate). Since you don't have the type of the object at compile time, enforcing `S extends T` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, I agree, but I know of many cases where a method signature such as the one of `work` is given by some external library for which you're not at liberty to change it. In those cases you need some workaround and if that workaround compiles without a warning, then it's all the better.

Answer (score 2):

Change `final Class<?> type` to `final Class<Object> type` (or to whatever concrete type you have). In your definition you have `S extends T` but if you pass in `Class<?>` you'd get `T = ?` and the compiler could not check whether `Object extends ?` (since `?` could be anything).

Edit:

Alternatively, change `work` to `<T, S> void work(final Class<T> type, final S object) {}`.

Comment: @Peter Yes, but his declaration states this as a requirement: `S extends T`. If this requirement is not that rigid (he's checking for `isInstance` anyway), then the declaration of `work` should just contain `<T, S>`.

Comment: How is `S extends T` more rigid than `isInstance`?

Comment: @Joachim `S extends T` is not more rigid, but the requirement itself is: The object passed in must be of type T or a subclass. `isInstance` just moves the check for this requirement to runtime. With `isInstance` you could just remove the compile time check.

Comment: This essentially does the same this as the chosen answer without the addition method declaration and is just as safe, additionally in my case it was <T extends MyClass> as well and i just cast the class object i got to Class<MyClass> instead of Class<? extends MyClass>, +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot check that the `object` is an instance of `type`. You can do this at runtime as you have done.  The simplest way to get this to compile is to use

```
final Class type = <not null>
```

This will give you a warning that the type is unchecked.